# typedefing a function return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Let's say I have a template function that returns a dependent type. Something like:

```
template <class T>
typename std::result_of<T()>::type
foo()
{
    std::result_of<T()>::type retVal;
    // Some mind blowing code...
    return retVal;
}
```

As you can see, I had to write the return type twice, once in the function type, and another time when declaring a local variable for the return value.

Is there a way I can `typedef` this type in the function signature so the type will be declared only once (No code duplication) and be visible and usable only inside the function (signature and body)?
Something like (Warning! pseudo code ahead, please don't be annoyed or inspired):

```
template <class T>
typedef typename std::result_of<T()>::type FooReturnType
FooReturnType foo()
{
    FooReturnType retVal;
    // Some mind blowing code...
    return retVal;
}
```

EDIT: I'm limited to a C++11 compiler.

Thanks

Comment: Try to do it as default template parameter

Comment: Or maybe auto return type if your compiler supports C++14?

Comment: @user3514538 Thought about it... but then the caller will be able to overwrite this value. I would need to `static_assert` that the second parameter is indeed the one I want (Still need to write the return type twice...) :(

Comment: @oLen Nope... I'm afraid C++14 is out of the question...

Comment: There isn't a perfect solution to this problem - if there was, the committee probably wouldn't have added `auto` for return types.  I'd go with the default template parameter, and if callers screw up ... they should have read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class T>
typename std::result_of<T()>::type
foo()
{
    decltype(foo()) retVal;
    // Some mind blowing code...
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: As asked, that's a brilliant solution.  If foo has lots of complex arguments in reality though, it's not going to be so good.  But have an upvote anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment says, there's this hack:

```
template <class T, typename Ret = std::result_of_t<T()>>
Ret foo() {
  Ret retVal;
  return retVal;
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to simply use return type deduction if your compiler is new enough:

```
template <class T>
auto foo() {
  std::result_of_t<T()> retVal;
  return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comments above. `auto` is out of the question (C++14 feature) and a default parameter is a bit problematic.

Comment: @user: Then you should add those requirements to your question.

Comment: @T.C.: Decaying is something that's going to have to happen, since he's not forwarding the results of `T`'s operator().

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template parameter that gets set to `std::result_of<T()>::type` like:

```
template <class T, class Ret = typename std::result_of<T()>::type>
Ret foo()
{
    Ret retVal = 100;
    // Some mind blowing code...
    return retVal;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b0ff4883c39223b)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Is this not why we allowed template typedefs via `using`?

```
template<typename T>
using Ret = typename std::result_of<T()>::type;

template<typename T>
Ret<T> foo()
{
    Ret<T> retVal;
    // Some mind blowing code...
    return retVal;
}
```

---

If you won't accept the traditional C++98/03 solution of a default template parameter, and you won't accept the C++11 solution of adding a `using` alias to the scope, and you can't use the C++14 solution of `auto` return type deduction, then there is no solution.

Comment: Yes but than the type will be visible to everyone that includes this header file. As I said in the question, I prefer avoiding that...

Comment: The only thing I do not like with this solution is it adds `Ret` to the global scope.  If you wanted to so this with a another and wanted `Ret` to be something different you would have to come up with another name.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Then stick it in a detail namespace or whatever.